# Importar ou add folder de um projeto antigo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Fiz um projeto e deu problema na solution. Tive que criar um novo projeto e agora estou adicionando os arquivos do antigo. O que passa que quando vou importar folders ele não importa, apenas arquivos. Até aí é razoável, pois o botão diz: Add existing item. Bem, há como eu importar um folder com todos os arquivos dentro dele? São muitos folders. Na pasta Script, eu tenho um folder de script para cada controller. São scripts relacionados apenas àquela controller.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido. Esqueci de algo importante. O `Include in Project`. Copiei as pastas para dentro e adicionei-as. Desculpe-me pela falta de observação a esse recurso. Valeu e obrigado.